# hibernate, jpa, c3p0, and warning HHH000208

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.6Final for accessing a JPA data source. While adding connection pooling via c3p0 I ran into this log message:

```
611  [main] WARN  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator  - HHH000208: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider has been deprecated in favor of org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider; that provider will be used instead.
```

Here are the hibernate artifacts from my POM:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and the relevant properties from `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="5" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="500" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="10000" />
```

I get the same warning even if I change the name of the provider to the favored class. What's the correct class name to use for `hibernate.connection.provider_class`? Is there a preferred connection provider for production use that's not c3p0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was observing the same warning for a while now and did not seen any impact on the functionality or performance of my app. But today I decided to switch the entry (as stated in the warning msg itself) in my **persistence.xml** to:

```
<!-- C3p0 connection pooling configuration -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
```

This solved the issue; I am also using **4.1.6Final**.